# Recoding a column in a data.frame conditional on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In my `tutorial` dataframe below, I'm trying to recode column `schgend` according to the following condition:

In rows where we have: `sex=="girl" & schgend =="girlsch"` OR we have: `sex=="boy" & schgend=="boysch"`, the values in column `schgend` must be recoded to `"same-sex"`. Otherwise, the  values in column `schgend` should remain unchanged.

I'm wondering, though, why my `ifelse()` call doesn't produce my desired outcome, is there a fix?

```
library(R2MLwiN)
data("tutorial")

transform(tutorial, schgend_new =ifelse(sex=="girl" & schgend=="girlsch" ||
                        sex=="boy" & schgend=="boysch","same-sex",schgend))
```

Comment: can you also add a reproducible data please.

Comment: @Macosso, the example in the question above is FULLY reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
tutorial$schgend_new <- ifelse(
    (tutorial$sex=="girl" & tutorial$schgend=="girlsch") |
    (tutorial$sex=="boy" & tutorial$schgend=="boysch"),
    "same-sex",
    tutorial$schgend)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)


tutorial_recoded <- tutorial %>%
  mutate(schgend_new = ifelse(sex=="girl" & schgend=="girlsch" | 
           sex=="boy" &  schgend=="boysch",
         "same-sex", schgend))
```

Comment: your code produces error. Would you please check it with the actual data.

Comment: would be great if you share a reproducible data that might help finding the error

Comment: the data is fully reproducible, what do you mean?